# store link clicks in json file

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a click counter, it works perfect for one link, but I want this code run for a multiple links

this is code that works perfectly for one link :

```
<a class="counter" href="#">Title</a>
```

js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var users = (function () {
    var users = null;
    $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': 'users.json',
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (data) {
        users = data.users_value;
      }
    });
    return users;
  })();
  $('#counter-number').text(users);

  $('.counter').click(function() {
    $.post("parser.php",{ajax: true});
  });
});
```

PHP code (parser.php) :

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('users.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$data['users_value'] += 1;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('users.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

json output :

```
{"users_value":17}
```

I want this code run for a multiple links like :

```
<a href="#" data-id="link1">title1</a>
<a href="#" data-id="link2">title2</a>
```

and store clicks of each link in json file separately

Comment: What do you mean code is not working? If you need to catch multiple links use class selector like you do. If you want to update something in the DOM traverse the code, using .find(), .parents() etc with $(this) combination

Comment: it worked for one link, i need store each link clicks in json by id, like this : {"link1":20, "link2":30}

Comment: then use data-linkid: property on the link, $(this).data("linkid")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code :
PHP

```
function objectToArray( $object ) {

if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
{
    return $object;
}
if( is_object( $object ) )
{
    $object = get_object_vars( $object );
}
return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}

function ip() {
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
$_SESSION["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

return $_SESSION["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
$last_dy = date("d") - 1;
if (file_get_contents('users_'.$last_dy.'_ip.json')) {
@unlink('users_'.$last_dy.'_ip.json');
}
if (!file_get_contents('users_'.date("d").'_ip.json')) {
file_put_contents('users_'.date("d").'_ip.json','[]');
}
$users_ip = objectToArray(json_decode(file_get_contents('users_'.date("d").'_ip.json')));
if (!is_object($users_ip) OR !is_array($users_ip)) {
$users_ip = array();
}
 if (!in_array(ip(), $users_ip)) {
$jsonString = file_get_contents('users.json');
$data = objectToArray(json_decode($jsonString));
$data['users_value'] = $data['users_value'] + 1;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('users.json', $newJsonString);
 array_push($users_ip, ip());
 }
 file_put_contents('users_'.date("d").'_ip.json', json_encode($users_ip));
```

you can used "function" in javascript code , is beter